How does a first order theory keep track of its axiom schemas?
From my understanding, an axiom schema is a meta-logical function symbol that takes an alphabet (or just the non-logical symbols) of your first order theory and gives you a collection of formulas as your axioms. You cannot just keep track of the axioms and forget about the schema if you ever want to extend your theory by adding non-logical symbols, in which case you will need to input you extended alphabet into the axiom schema again to generate your axioms. But how does a first-order theory, a meta-logical object, keep track of a meta-logical function symbol, which is sort of a meta-meta-logical object or a meta-logical class? This would not be a problem if we have a collection of all possible symbols,
but what if "all possible symbols" is a meta-logical proper class? What is the standard practice to encode an axiom schema, not just the generated axioms, into a first order theory?

There's no such "dynamic" setup at all. If you change the language, you need to change the theory too; it doesn't automatically keep up with your language modification. That said, if you go to an expansion by definitions you may find that no expansion of the theory is needed (beyond the relevant defining axioms), but that's - again - not a case of a language-sensitive theory.

I do believe that viewing an axiom schema as a meta-logical function symbol is at least convenient for generating logical axioms when given any alphabet. But now I also believe that a first order theory cannot keep track of its axiom schemas. If we ever need to reuse an axiom schema, we will need to explicitly reference it, instead of retrieving it from the theory.
